# How I can use exist table in mysql using typeorm entity?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

Using typeorm, I connect to the mysql db. Several tables already exist in the database. I try to describe a table using the entity module, but my definition overwrites an existing table. How with entity I can fully inherit from an existing table?

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, PrimaryColumn, OneToMany } from "typeorm";

@Entity("devices")
export class Devices {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    ID: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 255 })
    Name: string;

    @Column({ type: "int", nullable: false })
    DevID: number;

    @Column({ type: "int", nullable: false })
    Longtitude: number;

    @Column({ type: "int", nullable: false })
    Latitude: number;

    @PrimaryColumn({ type: "varchar", length: 255 })
    URL_VWS: string;
}
```

Comment: How is your table defined in Mysql, you should provide the schema of it as it is impossible to answer your question without

Comment: You should also provide the `ormconfig.json` file, with migrations and sync information. If you're using the `sync` option you won't be able to deal with it safely.

Answer (score 10):

You could set the the synchronize property to false with @Entity like below.

```
@Entity({name:"devices", synchronize: false})
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. Regarding the synchronize option, "entities marked with false are skipped from schema updates". More info found here: https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/entity

Answer (score 2):

In ormconfig.json

change

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "database": "demo",
  "username": "root",
  "entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

to

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "database": "demo",
  "username": "root",
  "entities": ["src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": false
}
```